# Optimization of a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN table_2 AS t2 on t1.t2Id = t2.Id
WHERE t1.Id >= 1000 
  AND t2.Name LIKE '%a%' --and a lot of others
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

--FROM and WHERE is similar to previous query 
SELECT @total = COUNT(*), @sum = SUM(t2.some_field)
FROM table_1 AS t1
JOIN table_2 AS t2 on t1.t2Id = t2.Id 
WHERE t1.Id >= 1000 AND t2.Name LIKE '%a%' --and a lot of others'
```

I'm interested in some "clean" variant of writing such a stored procedure. I want to separate similar code in one place to avoid errors when somebody will forget to copy-paste WHERE section

Now I'm thinking about temporary table. Maybe somebody have better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: How about creating a view?

Comment: You would be able to use Window Functions, except you are also using OFFSET and FETCH so probably not.... guess view is best solution

Comment: In SQL Server, a query can either return rows or assign variables, but not both.  Hence, you will need two queries.  That said, I'm not a fan of stored procedures returning rows at all.  Can you do what you want with a table-valued function?

Comment: `OFFSET .... FETCH` ***requires*** an `ORDER BY` which you are not showing ....

Comment: @GordonLinoff  "I'm not a fan of stored procedures returning rows at all" Why is that? thanks

Comment: @Horaciux . . . That is what table-valued functions are for.  Stored procedures should be for encapsulating application logic, not for executing queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a 2 step processing, you will need to run the query twice. What you can do is to store the data into a `#temporary` table, or a `@variable` table. The trick here would be to minimize the data that you store, so use `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT` to limit the data you're going to store in temp or variable table.

One way to re-write the query is:

```
    SELECT *, SUM(TotalAmount) OVER () AS SomeSum, COUNT(1) OVER () TotalRows
    INTO    #tmp
    FROM    table_1 AS t1
            JOIN table_2 AS t2 on t1.t2Id = t2.Id
    WHERE t1.Id >= 1000 AND t2.Name LIKE '%a%' --and a lot of others
    ORDER BY 1 --<<<<<< Mandatory
    OFFSET 20 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

    SELECT  TOP 1
            @Sum    = SomeSum,
            @Total  = TotalRows
    FROM    #tmp

    SELECT  * --<< except SomeSum, TotalRows columns
    FROM    #tmp
```

Just note the `ORDER BY` which is mandatory with `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT`.
Also, `SUM` and `COUNT` will still work on the entire result set, even if the results are limited by `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT`.

Hope it makes sense.